# Loading image from server using volley

Tags: java, php, android, json, android-volley

I'm trying to load images from my local server to my android app using Volley. I can access all the data strings from the json response and parse them but i can't get to load the image from my local server. If i use a online link to load a image it loads flawlessly but with local server i'm getting this error

```
NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL 192.168.1.10/myserver/uploads/dj_profilepic.png
```

i can access this link on my browser and it loads the image.

Comment: how you load the image into your app?? did you use any library ???

Comment: i'm using volley to load images from url..

Comment: You cannot just access the file which is placed in a directory on a host machine via http. Try putting it in a container like apache tomcat and then download it.

Comment: is your firewall off ?

Comment: @Jain can you please say it in a bit easy words. i'm sorry i'm not that pro in this stuff.. btw Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Armen yap Firewall is turned off..

Comment: @Jain what if i use a online hosting to save my images and then use the online link to load images.. will it still require the apache tomcat ?

Comment: Apace tomcat is a service you run on your machine to hold your web application and other data. If you are using a hosting site then you don't need anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add "http://" on url,and check the url is avaliable on phone's browser

Answer (score 0):

In easy words if you pc is windows you can download and install E.G wamp server which include also apache server -> http://www.wampserver.com/en/

then place all your images in `C:\wamp\www\uploads` folder you have to create `uploads` folder there then if your firewall and if your device are in same network as you pc you should be able to see your images by link - `YOUR_PC_IP/uploads/dj_profilepic.png`

Comment: i'm doing the same.. hosting files using xamp server.
http:// solved my issue.. :)